# How do I get the email address of currently logged in user? (Android Studio / Java / Firebase)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I just recently discovered firebase and found out I could probably use it for my finals. I am developing an app that users will have fixed login details given by "admin".

I want to be able to store the email address used to login to a variable, which I will then use for a reference pointing to a particular value to be updated in the realtime database.

> User A logs in
>
> > clicks a button
> >
> > > updates a value in realtime database under User A's email address directory (*app/usera/value*)
>
> User B logs in
>
> > clicks a button
> >
> > > updates a value in realtime database under User B's email address directory (*app/userb/value*)

I want to be able to change *usera* and *userb* to a variable *email* that gets its value upon user login.
Researching I found out from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo) that I can user getEmail() under UserInfo to achieve this. But I could not find any examples on how to do this nor code snips trying to do the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `mAuth` from firebase after your users logged in.

First declare the auth

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
```

then initialize it (onCreate)

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

and then after the user is logged in you can get the email:

```
String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
```

That's all.

ps: Also, after calling `getCurrentUser()`. you can get a lot of things from the user , like user ID, user photo url , user metadata, user display name and more !

Comment: Hmmm, and I will be able to use email as a child?
like
`myRef("Users").child(email).setValue("yes");`
...if that is all I need to do I will have to review my code since the application keeps on closing when I try to test it.

Will get back to you asap, as coding brought me up to the wee hours of the night and I still have class later.

Comment: yep, you can use myRef("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail()).. or myRef("Users").child(email)

Comment: Just updating you... thanks again for the quick reply, still can't figure out why application keeps on closing when I try to run it though so I dont have an unpdate on my app's progress, thanks though

Comment: can you give me some log when it crashes?

Comment: Not really sure what you are looking for so pasted the whole log into a privnote [link](https://privnote.com/tq1JMPwb#fWFCKZJQM)

Comment: your problem is this :  Invalid Firebase Database path  ... can you please share to me where you declare your database reference and how your database is estructured in your firebase console ?

Comment: private DatabaseReference myRef;
private FirebaseDatabase myDb;
myDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = myDb.getReference();
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
myRef = myDb.getReference("user").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());

db structure:
user
 ~email#1
  ~name
 ~email#2
  ~name

Comment: can you take a pic of your structure please

Comment: look, try this , myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); and then use this.  myRef.child("user").....

Comment: [Pic](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/329183648425181194/413693805221380108/unknown.png)
unit01 was being used for testing
unit01@thesis is supposed "final"
i am using a email = email.replace(".com", "");
to remove the .

Comment: did you make a log so you can see if the output is the email without .com ?

Comment: ... No, I did not encounter making a log in the tutorial vid i watched prior to starting. Will go search, learn, and try and then update.

Comment: because maybe you are not getting your email right, just do this , Log.e("emailOutput",""+email); and you can see when you execute in your logcat the email

Comment: E/emailOutput: unit01@thesis
So email checks out. But checking [firebase database](https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/b78f3954-eccc-4c65-9b4b-14f09ad3679d.png)
it updated a different value. rechecking code then will update

Comment: Cleaned then rebuilt code. Then it worked.
Sorry for all the trouble and thank you.